# Force Presto to maintain order of WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, hadoop, presto

I'm trying to run something like the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE cardinality(bar) > 0 AND bar[1] = '...';
```

However, I'm getting `Query failed: Array subscript out of bounds`. I'm assuming this is because Presto is trying to optimize the query by checking `bar[1] = '...'` before checking `cardinality(bar) > 0`. Is there a way to force Presto to maintain the order of the clauses?

Comment: SQL is not short-circuit. You can use `if` or `case` if you need particular evaluation order. In your particular case, the answer below makes total sense.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this in two ways when I've needed it.

1. Use [the `element_at` function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#element_at) instead of the [] subscript notation. `element_at` returns a NULL when indexing past the end of an array, so you could reduce your example to one condition. `element_at` also works in the SELECT clause, although it isn't needed with your WHERE clause:

```sql
SELECT bar[1] FROM foo WHERE element_at(bar,1) = '...';
```

2. Do the first condition in a subquery using [the `with` clause](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#with-clause):

```sql
WITH (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE cardinality(bar) > 0) AS populated_foo
SELECT * FROM populated_foo WHERE bar[1] = '...';
```

The 2nd approach doesn't make much sense for your example, but I've found it useful for more complex conditions involving row objects inside of arrays.